# How can I solve the output in a void method that needs toString

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I am working in an example, and I can't solve the output ID according the array I am using in the method getAlumno(i).

I know I must use toString to solve, however all the combinations fail.
Can you help me?

```
public Alumno getAlumno(int nAlumno) {  
    return arrayAlumnos[nAlumno];   
}       

public void getDatoAlumno(String nombreAlumno) {

    for(int i=0; i<arrayAlumnos.length;i++) {

        if(this.getAlumno(i)!=null) {

            if(arrayAlumnos[i].getNombreAlumno().equals(nombreAlumno)){             

                System.out.println("Nombre del Alumno: " + arrayAlumnos[i].getNombreAlumno() + 
                "\n" +  "Colegio: " + nombre + "\n" + "ID: " + this.getAlumno(i) + "\n" +
                arrayAlumnos[i].getNotaMedia());

                System.out.println("");         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output the ID number, not ID: com.nuevavidanz.colegio.Alumno@15db9742

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is unclear.  Please [edit] your question to include precisely what you are expecting and why you are expecting it, as well as what is actually happening.

Comment: Per generally agreed upon Java bean standards, a `getXxx()` type method should not be a void method. It should return the value suggested by its name. I'd also get all the printing **out** of that method and **in** the code that calls this method.

Comment: Please put the alumno class. You are printing the instance alumno this.getAlumno(i) instead this.getAlumnoID(i) or something like that

Answer (score 1):

### You have two solutions:

- Override toString method in the **Alumno** class.

*You said you tried but it didn't work. Can we see the implementation?*

- Second just call the id variable when you are calling this.getAlumno(i) function.

Try with: **this.getAlumno(i).getId()** if you have get method written or **this.getAlumno(i).id** if your variables are **public**